# How can I prove by induction that the second of these two algorithms is faster?

Tags: performance, algorithm, proof, induction

I have two algorithms.

```
A. Solves problem in 2^n seconds.

B. Solves problem in n^2 + 1,000,000 seconds.
```

How can I **inductively prove** that B is faster than A.

I'm told that 2^n > 2n+1 for n>2 might be useful for this problem. I've been cracking my head and can't solve this problem. Thanks.

"n" is equivalent to the size of the program.

EDIT: **For all n > 19.**

SOLUTION:

Premise: n^2 + 1,000,000 < 2^n

Basis:
n = 20
1000400 < 1048576 TRUE

Induction:

```
(n+1)^2 + 1000000 > 2^(n+1)
n^2 +2n +1 +1000000 > 2^(n+1)
Apply 2^n > 2n + 1
n^2 + 1000000 > 2^(n+1)
```

This last line implies that B is always bigger than A.

Comment: Yes, n being the size of the program. So from small to very large.

Comment: Differentiate 3 times.

Comment: Sorry, for all n > 19.

Comment: This is more like a math problem than programming...

Comment: Well, 2^20 is 1,048,576. 20^2 is 400, so 20^2 + 1,000,000 is 1,000,400. And since 2^21 is much larger than 21^2 ...

Comment: It's analysis of algorithms. O(2^n) > O(n^2) -- exponential vs. geometric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the base case is proven.
ie `k^2<2^k for k>=5`

For the induction, let us assume that

```
k^2<2^k
```

We need to prove that

```
(k+1)^2<2^(k+1)

(k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1 < 2^k + 2k + 1
```

We know that `(k-1)^2>=0.` thus `k^2>=2k-1`

```
2^k + 2k + 1 = 2^k + 2k -1 + 2 <= 2^k + k^2 + 2 < 2^k + 2^k +2= 2^(k+1) + 2
```

Argh, i feel like im almost there. any help?

Comment: Induction involves proving for an initial value before moving to k, k+1. This is not included in the answer.

Comment: Yes, typically prove for 1, assume for k, and deduce for k+1. MI works when the statement is valid for all natural numbers. So applying the logic of 2^n > n^2 wont work!

Comment: The base would be n = 20. The induction step is the hard part. Would you mind adding the intermediate steps (including when you use the induction hypothesis)?

Comment: Why is the base case n=20, doing some mental calculations i can see that k^2<2^k for k>=5

Comment: Because it's n^2 + 1,000,000. B is only faster when n > 19.

Comment: I think I got the answer. I'll accept your answer because it got me started in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: @amorimluc Can you paste your answer as well.. Just not able to get the final step in here.. Thanks for the voetup

Answer (score 2):

B will only be faster if n > 19.9321. If you don't need the actual work, then [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5En%20%3E%20n%5E2%20%2b%201000000) is where I got the answer from.

For any numbers less than 19.9321, then A will be faster.

Comment: +1 However, `n` is almost certainly going to be an integer in this case.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is how to go about proving that B is faster through `induction`.

Answer (score 1):

Python as a calculator:

```
>>> n = 20
>>>
>>> 2**n
1048576
>>> n**2 + 1000000
1000400
>>>
```